# convert bytes or bytearray to struct

Tags: python, data-conversion

I have the below classes that come from C definitions
The classes/structs were needed to interpret a binary stream into readable classes/information.

```py
class D_1ByteText(c_uint8):
    NY_No = 0x00
    NY_Yes = 0x01

class STR_4ByteStruc(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ("val1", c_int32),
    ]

class STR_12ByteStruc(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ("val2",  c_int32),
        ("val3",  c_int32),
        ("val4",  c_int32),
    ]


class STR_17ByteStruc(Structure):
    """
    typedef struct {
        STR_4ByteStruc MeasuA;
        STR_12ByteStruc MeasuB;
        D_1ByteText MeasuAvail;
    }STR_17ByteStruc;
    """
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ("MeasuA", STR_4ByteStruc),
        ("MeasuB", STR_12ByteStruc),
        ("MeasuAvail", D_1ByteText),
    ]
    

    
def vdd_decode_from_bytes(self, bin_bytes):

    size = sizeof(STR_17ByteStruc())
    if len(bin_bytes) != size:
        return None

    measure_struct = STR_17ByteStruc()
    memmove(pointer(measure_struct), bin_bytes, size)

    self.measurement_available = measure_struct.MeasuAvail.value
    self.val1 = measure_struct.MeasuA.val1
    self.val2 = measure_struct.MeasuB.val2
    self.val3 = measure_struct.MeasuB.val3
    self.val4 = measure_struct.MeasuB.val4
```

The `bin_bytes` as a hexstring is "acfffffffaffffffb2ffffff2400000001".

So calling `vdd_decode_from_bytes(bin_bytes)` leads to an object with members `val1`...`val4`

That is working.

My problem now is the reverse way.

Having an object with `val1`...`val4` set, how can I encode it to have the same binary data as before?

Answer (score 2):

Two ways: one using `ctypes` and one using `struct`:

For `ctypes`, I simplified the structure but it has the same layout for 32-bit signed integers and an unsigned byte.  It works with nested structures, too.  `.from_buffer_copy()` can be used with `bytes` or `bytearray` data, but `.from_buffer` works with mutable memory only and will reference the same memory.  Change the memory content and the structure will change as well.

```py
import ctypes as ct
import struct

class MyStruct(ct.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = (('val1', ct.c_int32),
                ('val2', ct.c_int32),
                ('val3', ct.c_int32),
                ('val4', ct.c_int32),
                ('avail', ct.c_uint8))

    # So structure can print itself
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'MyStruct(val1={self.val1}, val2={self.val2}, ' \
               f'val3={self.val3}, val4={self.val4}, avail={self.avail})'

def vdd_decode_from_bytes(bin_bytes):
    return MyStruct.from_buffer_copy(bin_bytes)

data = bytes.fromhex('acfffffffaffffffb2ffffff2400000001')
s = vdd_decode_from_bytes(data)
print(s)       # via __repr__
print(s.val1)  # still access individual values
print(s.val2)
print(s.val3)
print(s.val4)
print(s.avail)
print(bytes(s).hex()) # convert back to byte stream (shown as hex)
```

Output:

```
MyStruct(val1=-84, val2=-6, val3=-78, val4=36, avail=1)
-84
-6
-78
36
1
acfffffffaffffffb2ffffff2400000001
```

For `struct`, here is simple packing and unpacking of byte structures: `<` means little-endian encoding, `4l` (little L) means 4 signed 32-bit integers.  `B` is an unsigned byte.

```
import struct

data = bytes.fromhex('acfffffffaffffffb2ffffff2400000001')
print(struct.unpack('<4lB', data))
print(struct.pack('<4lB', -84, -6, -78, 36, 1).hex())
```

Output:

```
(-84, -6, -78, 36, 1)
acfffffffaffffffb2ffffff2400000001
```

You can also do:

```
val1, val2, val3, val4, avail = struct.unpack('<4lB', data)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. But in original I have many nested structures.
In my answer I tried to simplify it a little bit, and also removed content that is not for pulic.

Comment: works perfect, Thanks.

One last question:
Is it possible to serialize such objects, even with nested structs ( from c-struct)?
@MarkTolonen
So in the example above I will have a dictionary with keys val1...val4, and with the values as the values in the dict.

I tried it with json.dumps, but always see an error message ( object not serializable )